# How to merge different data frames which include both identical and different row and column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

Here is the example:

Sample data frame 1:

[image: Sample data frame 1]

Sample data frame 2:

[image: Sample data frame 2]

The output data frame should be something like this:

[image: The output data frame]

Max() of similar terms should be considered if the row - column value is repeating in data frames.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Images dont help with reproducing your code. Please add code snippets instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use pd.concat for this.

You could refer this pandas doc
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou for the Help @Vignesh

pd.concat([df_A, df_B], axis=0).fillna(0).groupby('col').max() gives the required result